# How to compare pairs by other field only in c++?

Tags: c++

Im having this issue with comparing pairs. I want use `find()` to my vector which contains pairs like this:

```
vector<pair<PersonID, Cost>> friendlist;
```

`PersonID` and `Cost` are both just regular ints. And the problem here is that I want to specifically use the `find()` just on the `PersonID`, I'm not interested on the `Cost`.

```
if(friendlist.begin(), friendlist.end(), std::make_pair(toid, Cost)) != 
friendlist.end() )
```

`toid` here is the id I want to look for within the vector. So what I should do with the other field that `make_pair` requires?

Comment: Take a look at `std::find_if()`. There is an overload where you can specify the function to be used to compare.

Comment: maybe `std::map` is better solution?

Answer (score 6):

```
std::find_if(friendlist.begin(), friendlist.end(),
  [=](const std::pair<PersonID, Cost>& elem) {
    return elem.first == toid;
  });
```